# What does Phoebe mean when she says "I bet they're doing it"

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

***Friends***: 'The One With All The Resolutions' (Season 5 Episode 11)

When Rachel and Joey find out that each of them knows about Chandler and Monica's secret affair Phoebe enters the apartment. Both of them go for a walk in the rain. Phoebe then says,

**"I bet they're doing it."**

What does she mean by that? Who is she referring to by 'they'?

Answer (score 8):

She means Rachel and Joey. She notices they have a secret and assumes they have an affair (by 'doing it' she means sex). This is funny especially because it's actually Monica and Chandler having an affair.